# how to loop for 2 data in same table in html with cycle tag

Tags: html, django

so i want to print list of manage user in my database , and i show it in the table that i make in html , but the problem is , when i open the web and see the list of manage user, the email and the username is in the same column

```
def manage_user(request):
    import cx_Oracle
    dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(, , ) 
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=, password=, dsn=dsn_tns) 
    c = conn.cursor() 
    c.execute("select * from auth_user")
    c.rowfactory = makeDictFactory(c)
    databaseusertable = []
    databaseemailtable =[]
    for rowDict in c:
        databaseusertable.append(rowDict['USERNAME'])
        databaseemailtable.append(rowDict['EMAIL'])

    context = {
        'obj' : databaseusertable,
        'obj2': databaseemailtable,
    }
    return render(request,'manage_user.html',context)
```

html

```
{% for item1 in obj %}
                  <tr>


                  <td>
                      {{item1}}
                  </td>
                  {% cycle '' '' '</td></tr><tr>' %}


                  </tr>
                  {% endfor %}
                  {% for item2 in obj2 %}
                  <tr>


                  <td>
                      {{item2}}
                  </td>
                  {% cycle '' '' '</td></tr><tr>' %}


                  </tr>
                  {% endfor %}
```

how to make the email is in the different column? i use cycle tags, thats why im a little bit confuse about it

Comment: Why not use the Django ORM? `User.objects.all()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming those lists are not used anywhere else in template, it's better that you build list of users in view, instead of 2 separate lists - easier to read and work with.

```py
def manage_user(request):
    import cx_Oracle
    dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(, , ) 
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=, password=, dsn=dsn_tns) 
    c = conn.cursor() 
    c.execute("select * from auth_user")
    c.rowfactory = makeDictFactory(c)
    databaseusertable = []
    for rowDict in c:
        databaseusertable.append({
            'name': rowDict['USERNAME'],
            'email': rowDict['EMAIL']
        })

    context = {
        'users' : databaseusertable,
    }
    return render(request,'manage_user.html',context)
```

After that you can simply loop over the list in template and built table:

```py
{% for user in users %}
<tr>
  <td>
    {{user.name}}
  </td>
  <td>
    {{user.email}}
  </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: AH YES!! , it really works,  thankyou , im trying to find how to append 2 column in 1 variable , and i dont know how thats why i make 2 array variable  .. so thats how it works, thankyouu!